# How can I swap the position of all pictures in a Word Document with the picture above?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

I have a Word document with a lot of pictures (they were added by drag & drop from the desktop and are saved in the file, not just linked to the files on the desktop), seperated by 0 to 2 lines of text, something like this:

```
Text
Text
Picture0
Text
Picture1
Picture2
Text
Picture3
...
```

The problem is that the pictures are offset by one, i.e. Picture1 should be where Picture0 is now, Picture2 where Picture1 is and so on. There are approximately 300 pictures and swapping them by hand would take too long. Is there an automated way to do this, perhaps with a macro?

Comment: Cut and paste the image you want into the correct position. Your question fails to state how you want this fixed! It also doesn't  state how they are embed (via VBa, via the ribbon or were the images copied and pasted, are they linked to files on a hard drive (or other souce)). Please [EDIT your question](http://superuser.com/posts/646396/edit) and provide this detail, then I will remove the -1

Comment: Alternate suggestion: don't move the pictures, move the text. Maybe that's easier?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a .docx file, or you can convert it to one, you might be able to do that by opening the archive (copy and rename to .zip), and renaming the files inside it.

Comment: This would probably work, but it still requires me to rename a huge amount of files, e.g. image2.png to image1.png. I couldn't figure out how to do this with a batch file, unfortunately.

Comment: You could probably do it with `FOR` at the command line; my preferred quick-and-dirty method would be to paste the file list into Excel (using `dir/b *.png >list.txt`) and generate the commands to rename them using string manipulation formulae.

Comment: In Excel: `="REN "&B2&" "&B1`. Then paste the commands into a command prompt window (remembering to delete image1.png first!).